# Why my Image(Yocto) can not apply change in rcar_canfd.c?

Tags: c++, yocto

I am a newbie in Yocto, I have a problem with rcar_canfd.c:
In my project I find rcar_canfd.c in:

```
./home/u/hungphung/S4_APD/build-spider-gateway/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/linux-libc-headers/5.10-r0/git/drivers/net/can/rcar/rcar_canfd.c
./home/u/hungphung/S4_APD/build-spider-gateway/tmp/work-shared/spider/kernel-source/drivers/net/can/rcar/rcar_canfd.c
```

I try to edit 2 file but when I build this source:

```
:~/hungphung/S4_APD$ ./build_yocto.sh spider gateway
```

yocto not build any new file

```
Sstate summary: Wanted 0 Found 0 Missed 0 Current 2250 (0% match, 100% complete)
```

How I can apply new edit?

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate build of a package, Yocto first copy all source to build directory, and in some of the next step compile it. If you try to edit file in build directory, it will be overridden next time you initiate build, and that is exactly what you are trying to do.

In order to get changes in the end product, you have to edit the original file. In `.bb` file, you should find `SRC_URI` variable and that is where the source file is located.

If you are getting source from local machine, then just edit your original file, and if source is downloaded from internet, you have to make patch files and add it in `.bb` file, but that is some other topic.

Comment: Hello @User19818359, Have you ever applied CanF to rcar whitebox? Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Dear @User19818359, How about ```SRC_URI``` , How to edit ```SRC_URI``` to link to local file source.

Comment: Take a look at this [bitbake user manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html) at 4.3 Fetcher. There is described how to fetch from url, file, etc.